# MariaDB Galera cluster node recovery max time

Tags: mariadb

I have a theoretical question about MariaDB Galera cluster. Let's say, one node breaks down and exits the cluster. What is the maximum time or log size, the node can come back to the cluster and start syncing before the node sails, the cluster  is too far ahead and unable to catch up with the most relevant information?

A "stupid" example: Let's say the cluster is at log position 1.000. Node3 exits at this point. Cluster moves one, reaches even log position 1.000.000 so it is quite far away. Is there a point where the Node3, when coming back, it will say it cannot  find the all the logs required to catch-up with the cluster because logs have moved on too far ahead. Like, on the  cluster servers the positions between 1.000 and 100.000 are gone forever, thus Node3 can get the logs from 100.001 to 1.000.000, but  missing the  logs from 1.001 to 99.999. Is this a real scenario and if yes, how can I adjust the settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the cluster is too far ahead, i.e. the required transactions aren't in the gcache, then a full state transfer occurs but using another node as the data orginal an sst mechanism (mysqldump, mariabackup or rsync as configured in [wsrep-sst-method](https://galeracluster.com/library/documentation/mysql-wsrep-options.html#wsrep-sst-method)).

ref:

- [State transfer](https://galeracluster.com/library/documentation/state-transfer.html)
- [Galera Recovery](https://galeracluster.com/library/documentation/crash-recovery.html)

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I was hoping for.